# Convert Java Collection<Integer> type to R object using JNI

Tags: java, r, java-native-interface

I have a java method which returns `collection<"Integer">` and I want to use it in R. The java method is as

```
public Collection<Integer> search( ){ ....}
```

Using JNI, What should be the type of this (Java collection) object in R. I tried with  `"[I"` , which means an integer array, but it did not worked.

Comment: AFAIK, when you're dealing with Java generics in JNI code you need to use the raw type, i.e. `Ljava/util/Collection;`

Comment: I tried with [Ljava/util/Collection;  but still with no luck.

Comment: `Ljava/util/Collection;`, not `[Ljava/util/Collection;`. It's not an array of `Collection`s.

Comment: I am sorry. I realized it now by using javap -s java.util.Collection. Your answer is working perfectly. Please add your first comment as an answer. I will accept it. May be someone  will need it.  Thanks once again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Collection<Integer>` is a type created by parameterizing the generic interface `Collection`, which allows some compile-time sanity checks to be performed on your usage of the `Collection<Integer>`.

However, at runtime, what remains of the `Collection<Integer>` is just [the *raw type*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html) `Collection`. So if you're trying to find the appropriate class with `FindClass` you should look for `java.util.Collection`, i.e. `"java/util/Collection"`.

Once you have a reference to the class and a reference to an instance of that class you could use the `toArray` method in `Collection` to get an ordinary array of `Integer` objects, if that's what you want.

---

A small semi-pointless example (assuming you have a `jobject intColl` which is referring to your `Collection<Integer>`):

```
// Get an array of Objects corresponding to the Collection
jclass collClass = env->FindClass("java/util/Collection");
jmethodID collToArray = env->GetMethodID(collClass, "toArray", "()[Ljava/lang/Object;");
jobjectArray integerArray = (jobjectArray) env->CallObjectMethod(intColl, collToArray);

// Get the first element from the array, and then extract its value as an int
jclass integerClass = env->FindClass("java/lang/Integer");
jmethodID intValue = env->GetMethodID(integerClass, "intValue", "()I");
jobject firstInteger = (jobject) env->GetObjectArrayElement(integerArray, 0);
int i = env->CallIntMethod(firstInteger, intValue);

__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, "Test", "The value of the first Integer is %d", i);

env->DeleteLocalRef(firstInteger);
env->DeleteLocalRef(integerArray);
```

Comment: Can you please specify something more about toArray. Where should I use it? in the `public Collection<Integer> search( ){ ....}` or somewhere in the JNI specification type for collection. A small example will be helpful

Comment: @HaroonRashid: I've added a code example. I also fixed a typo (the string you should pass to `FindClass` is `"java/util/Collection"`, not `"Ljava/util/Collection;"`)